# addEventListener drop not firing

Tags: javascript, events, drag-and-drop

I am trying to attach a drop event to an HTML div:

```
document.getElementById('sub-main').addEventListener("drop", 
                                     () => {console.log('DROP')});
```

but it does not fire. Adding a click event for test purposes worked - this click event fires:

```
document.getElementById('sub-main').addEventListener("click", 
                                     () => {console.log('Click')});
```

I have read that returning false from `ondragover` will help:

```
document.getElementById('sub-main').addEventListener("ondragover", 
                                     () => {return false});

document.getElementById('sub-main').addEventListener("drop", 
                                     () => {console.log('Drop')});
```

But this does not work either. I tried setting `draggable` to true:

```
document.body.setAttribute('draggable', true);
```

But also no luck!

Logging the event listeners to the console with `getEventListeners()`  shows all the events, even any random event name I chose:

```
getEventListeners(document.getElementById('sub-main'));
```

But the drop event still does not fire. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `ondrop` instead of `drop` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but according to this link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondrop.asp it is drop

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_ondrag_all 
works perfectly fine for me

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović that is the correct answer - if you add it as an answer I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 36):

To enable dragging you should first of all disable the default behavior of the browser using the **dragover** event.

add this piece of code and it will work.

```
document.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: was pulling my hair out until i found this. thank you.

Comment: Thank you! If I had a pie I would send to you

Answer (score 1):

I did some trial and error in plunker and came to the conclusion that you first need to set the eventListener on the document(dont use.getElementById('sub-main') gives error in plunker at least) and then specify in the eventlistener on which target to fire on. And for it to detect that it can be dropped you need to have other eventListeners like: drag, dragstart, dragover, dragleave and dragenter. [Just follow what they did here on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drop)